# Bootstrap - prevent div to expand due to a bigger text

Tags: html, css

I'm having the below source code in `HTML` that basically is a Bootstrap card:

```
<div class="card shadow-none card-fluid mb-3 mb-md-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
            <img class="img-fluid rounded"
                src="{% static 'img url' %}"
                alt="Image Description">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="card-header py-md-0 py-lg-0 py-xl-0 pl-0 pr-0">
                <h6 class="h5 mb-3">Text of 100 characters Text of 100 characters Text of 100 
                characters Text of 100 characters Text of 100 characters
                </h6>
                <p class="font-size-1">
                    Text of 20 characters.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body p-0 px-0 py-md-0 py-lg-0 py-xl-0">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-8 text-left">
                        <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center">
                            <span class="static-rating static-rating-sm d-block mr-2">
                                <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i>
                                <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i>
                                <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i>
                                <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i>
                                <i class="fas fa-star-half-alt text-warning"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <span class="d-inline-block">
                            <h6 class="mt-0 mb-2">4.95/5
                                <small class="text-white-70">(1.5k+)</small>
                            </h6>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer p-3 py-md-2 py-lg-2 mt-xl-5">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <button type="button"
                            class="btn btn-sm btn-link btn-icon-label hover-translate-y-n3">
                            <span class="btn-inner--icon btn-cust-icon">
                                <i class="mr-1" data-feather="edit-3"></i>
                            </span>
                            <span class="btn-inner--text">Edit</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 text-right">
                        <button type="button"
                            class="btn btn-xs btn-outline-danger btn-icon-label hover-translate-y-n3">
                            <span class="btn-inner--icon">
                                <i data-feather="trash-2"></i>
                            </span>
                            <span class="btn-inner--text">Delete</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue I'm facing is that depending on the size of the text within `card-header` class, the `div` corresponding to the one having class `card-footer` it moves up or down. Is there any way to keep the `card-footer` static and only to limit the size of the text to let's say 120 chars?

**Edit**

Added the following snippet:

```css
.custom-css {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  /* number of lines to show */
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<li class="card shadow-none card-fluid mb-3 mb-md-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
      <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="{% static 'img url' %}" alt="Image Description">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div class="card-header py-md-0 py-lg-0 py-xl-0 pl-0 pr-0">
        <h6 class="h5 mb-3 custom-css">Text 100 charactersText 100 charactersText 100 charactersText 100 charactersText 100 charactersText 100 charactersText 100 charactersText 100 charactersText 100 characterscharactersText 100 charactersText 100 charactersText 100 charactersText
          100 charactersText 100 charactersText 100 charactersText 100 characterscharactersText 100 charactersText 100 charactersText 100 charactersText 100 charactersText 100 charactersText 100 charactersText 100 characters
        </h6>
        <p class="font-size-1">
          Text length medium
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body p-0 px-0 py-md-0 py-lg-0 py-xl-0">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-8 text-left">
            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center">
              <span class="static-rating static-rating-sm d-block mr-2">
                                                            <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i>
                                                            <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i>
                                                            <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i>
                                                            <i class="fas fa-star text-warning"></i>
                                                            <i class="fas fa-star-half-alt text-warning"></i>
                                                        </span>
            </a>
            <span class="d-inline-block">
                                                        <h6 class="mt-0 mb-2">4.95/5
                                                            <small class="text-white-70">(1.5k+ review-uri)</small>
                                                        </h6>
                                                    </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could give it a `min-height` and `max-height` and also `min-width` and `max-width` to sort of contain it between these values.

Comment: To `card-footer` class?

Comment: yeah the one you want fixed

Comment: I wasn't able to achieve the desired result. I've added `min/max-height` but for sure I'm missing something. Would it be possible to post an example based on my source code? Thanks

Comment: can you add this to a jsfiddle or snippet so i can take a look

Comment: I've edited my post. I want that the 2nd `div` - `card-body` to be fixed and responsive regardless the size of the text from `card-header`.

Comment: you're snippet doesn't include bootstrap try adding the head of the document in here as well

Comment: Apart from linking to Bootstrap CDN there is nothing more.